# Which subdomains can I use when I register a UK domain (.co.uk, .ac.uk, etc)?

Tags: domains, top-level-domains

I can register a .uk domain, does this mean I can set any subdomain I like infront of it including .co?
Or even .ac?
Wouldn't this mean that anyone can get an .ac.uk domain by just having ac as a subdomain on a  .uk domain?

Is a .co.uk domain all one TLD or is the .co just a subdomain preadded by domain registrars?

Answer (score 5):

> I can register a .uk domain

Yes, for example: `example.uk` (`example` is your registered domain name.)

> does this mean I can set any subdomain I like infront of it including .co?

Yes, for example: `co.example.uk` (`co` is a subdomain of the domain `example.uk` you have just registered).

> Wouldn't this mean that anyone can get an .ac.uk domain by just having ac as a subdomain on a .uk domain?

No, see above.

> Is a .co.uk domain all one TLD or is the .co just a subdomain preadded by domain registrars?

Strictly speaking, the `co` is a subdomain (second level domain / SLD) of the `uk` TLD (top level domain).

However, for the sake of registration, `co.uk` is a TLD. Being able to register SLDs under `.uk` is a relatively recent addition.

Answer (score 4):

Can you register any domain under .uk?

Not entirely: [until 10 July 2019](http://www.dotuklaunch.uk/im-existing-customer) owners of .co.uk, .org.uk, .me.uk and .net.uk have first refusal for the equivalent .uk domains (in that order in case of different owners).

As w3d points out `.co` and `.ac` are technically SLDs of the main .uk domain and stay registered and managed as they are, along with the restrictions on them: so to purchase a .ac.uk domain for example you still need to be an accredited academic institution, similarly for .ltd.uk and .plc.uk.

Basically the existing owner of a SLD has the right to enforce whatever restrictions they like on the purchasing of sub-domains, and some of these are still in place to ensure the validity of the domains, for details of these domains check out Nominet.UK's page on the .UK domain: http://nominet.uk/domains/our-domains/uk-domains/

Answer (score 0):

To do as you wish, you would have to register either co.uk or ac.uk as two-letter .uk domain names. Neither is possible.